# Magento1 admin product image upload issue

Tags: magento-1.9, error, adminhtml, product-images, admin-panel

I have installed Magento1 Patch `SUPEE-8788` in my local system. But I have an issue, in Admin Panel, Product Image Upload Browse Button is Not Working.

[image]

1 File: `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Media\Uploader.php`

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Media_Uploader extends Mage_Uploader_Block_Multiple
{
    /**
     * Constructor for uploader block
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->getUploaderConfig()->setTarget(Mage::getModel('adminhtml/url')->addSessionParam()->getUrl('*/*/upload'));
        $this->getUploaderConfig()->setFileParameterName('file');
    }
}
```

2 File: `app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\media\uploader.phtml`

```
<?php
/**
 * @var $this Mage_Uploader_Block_Multiple|Mage_Uploader_Block_Single
 */
?>
<div id="<?php echo $this->getHtmlId() ?>" class="uploader">
    <div class="buttons a-right">
        <?php echo $this->getBrowseButtonHtml(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->getUploadButtonHtml(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="no-display" id="<?php echo $this->getElementId('template') ?>">
    <div id="{{id}}-container" class="file-row">
        <span class="file-info">{{name}} {{size}}</span>
        <span class="delete-button"><?php echo $this->getDeleteButtonHtml() ?></span>
        <span class="progress-text"></span>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function() {
        var uploader = new Uploader(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig(); ?>);

        if (varienGlobalEvents) {
            varienGlobalEvents.attachEventHandler('tabChangeBefore', uploader.onContainerHideBefore);
        }
    })();
</script>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('additional_scripts'); ?>
```